# Normal folder is not displayed in eclipse src/test/resources source folder

Tags: eclipse

As displayed in screenshot, I am not able to create normal folder in scr/test/resources source folder. Whenever I create normal folder it show something different icon than normal folder.
How to solve the issue and make my 'ATUReporter' folder displayed as normal folder.

[image]

Comment: the folder structure shown above is of the correct format so not sure why you'd want to differ from that?

Comment: I have created a normal folder ATUReporter inside there is Result folder and then Run_1, Run_2 and so on. It should show in tree format. Currently its not the normal folder